# Ansible is not working on mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ansible

I'm trying to execute ansible in my system. I guess I messed up something and unable to run ansible. When I run ansible --version, I see the following error:

```
krishnapatamset:bin krishna.patamsetti$ ansible --version
[WARNING]: log file at /var/log/ansible/ansible.log is not writeable   and we cannot create it, aborting

ERROR! Unexpected Exception: No module named markupsafe
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/ansible", line 80, in <module>
from ansible.cli.adhoc import AdHocCLI as mycli
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/adhoc.py",  line 28, in <module>
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 29, in <module>
from ansible.executor.play_iterator import PlayIterator
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/play_iterator.py", line 30, in <module>
from ansible.playbook.block import Block
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 27, in <module>
from ansible.playbook.base import Base
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 29, in <module>
from jinja2.exceptions import UndefinedError
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 13, in <module>
from jinja2 import nodes
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
from jinja2.utils import Markup
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 531, in <module>
from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: No module named markupsafe
```

Can anyone please help me with this situation. Thanks in advance
I even tried pip install markupsafe but still I am unable to get ansible working

Comment: Are you sure that you used pip of python 3 not 2 ??

Comment: I used both pip and pip2 as well. But nothing changed

Comment: How did you install Ansible? What's the result of `type pip`?

Comment: I did `pip install asnible`

Comment: Are you going to answer the other question?

Comment: I use `pip install --user ansible` on my mac

Comment: sorry for the delay. I did uninstall pip and resintalled it and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is based on python and there is a python module that's missing called `markupsafe`

install it via pip, you may need to escalate privileges

```
pip2 install -I markupsafe
```

`pip2` for python 2.x

`-I` to ignore and reinstall package if it's already installed

Comment: Used -I flag and still I'm seeing the same issue

Comment: What's the output of pip ?

Comment: `krishnapatamset:~ krishna.patamsetti$ pip -V
  pip 9.0.1 from   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: krishnapatamset:etc krishna.patamsetti$ pip install -I markupsafe
Collecting markupsafe
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: markupsafe
  Running setup.py install for markupsafe

Comment: It installed successfully and again I tried ansible --version and still i'm seeing same old problem

Comment: Try to uninstall it, delete the folder from site-packages if remains.. Then install

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled pip and installed it again.
`brew uninstall pip`
`brew doctor`
`brew install pip`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

`brew uninstall ansible-lint ansible python-markupsafe`

`brew install ansible-lint ansible python-markupsafe`